# Why do the outputs for Binet's formula have decimals when calculated using Python?

Tags: python, math, fibonacci

I'm writing a script in Python that returns a list of terms in the Fibonacci sequence, given a start term and an end term. For example, if I entered "0" as the start term and "6" as the end term, then the output should be:

```python
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Oddly, when I ran the program, the output was:

```python
[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004, 5.000000000000001, 8.000000000000002]
```

To calculate the terms of the sequence, I used Binet's formula, which I entered as `((1 + math.sqrt(5))**x -(1 - math.sqrt(5))**x) / (2**x * math.sqrt(5)))`. I entered the same formula into a few other calculators to see if they'd give me decimal answers, and none of them did. Did I somehow mistype the formula, or is Python miscalculating it?

Comment: It is due to how Python displays floating point numbers. Python uses a different display method to calculators in that Python often displays more decimal points than calculators do. 
All floating point calculations are inherently inaccurate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers lose some precision due to storage issues. [See "Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations" for details](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

In this simple case you can just use `round()` to get integers again. But beware: this can also lead to errors.

```py
print([
    round(
        ((1 + math.sqrt(5))**x - (1 - math.sqrt(5))**x)
        / (2**x * math.sqrt(5))
    )
    for x in range(10)
])
```

results in

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```